# disk usage application

Tags: disk

How can I get separate assigned path disk usage by crontab job to do it? For example, I would like to find out the path as list as below
ex:

```
/var/example/attachments/ver003/112/24

/var/example/attachments/ver003/10/13/12

/var/example/attachments/ver003/119/12
```

How can I use du -sh to got their disk usage by crontab or sh file to output the result?
output: `path1:10GB`

```
path2:20MB

path3:850MB
```

Comment: Could you try to reformulate? I'm not sure what you're asking for. Something like look for partitions matching a pattern and check for space used? Are those arbitrary folders, or mount points for network or block devices? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```bash
for i in /var/example/attachments/ver003/112/24 /var/example/attachments/ver003/10/13/12 /var/example/attachments/ver003/119/12; do 
    du $i -sh | awk -v p=$i '{print p,":",$1;}'
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my code is as listed as below: or i in /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence/attachments/ver003/90/26 /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence/attachments/98/26; do (enter next) du &i -sh | awk -v p=$i '{print p,":",$1;}' (enter next) done
But when I run , it show message : line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Well, this is strange. I gave you three lines of code, and you say the error is in line 6. However, in your post you are missing letter `f` at the beginning. It should say `for` and not `or`. Then you have `&i` instead of `$i` in the second line.

Comment: thanks a lot. It's ok. But can I give each path a name, not real path? For example path1 120MB, path2 1GB, path3, 251MB.